# How to render a string with variables rather than a template file in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I can easily render a template with variables from a file with some code like:

```
    $renderer = new PhpRenderer();
    $vm = new ViewModel();
    $resolver = new TemplateMapResolver();


    $resolver->setMap($this->templateMap);
    $renderer->setResolver($resolver);

    // Set the template to use and pass in variables as you normally would a view
    $vm->setTemplate($template);
    if ($vars) {
        $vm->setVariables($vars);

    }
    $content = $renderer->render($vm);
```

I am curious how I can provide a `string` to `setTemplate` rather than a path to a template file. This way, the content being passed in can come from various sources such as an administrator's panel or database.

Answer (score 1):

In **[the configuration example in the documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html#configuration)** you can see that it is possible to define a `template_map` inside your `view_manager` config array. A template map is like an array of aliases for your template files. So inside your `module.config.php`:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    //...
    'template_map' => array(
        'name_from_admin_panel' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/view.phtml',
        'name_from_database' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/view.phtml',
    )
    //...
)
```

Now you can use these names from your template map to set the template in your `ViewModel` as normally:

```
$template = 'name_from_admin_panel';
$viewModel->setTemplate($template);
```

Comment: I've already done this method, but what if there is no view.phtml, as in it is being made dynamically--That is what I meant by creating it from a string.

Comment: @user49438, well that was not how I interpreted: *"I am curious how I can provide a string to setTemplate rather than a path to a template file"*. So what you get from a database or admin panel is plain html in a string?

Comment: It would be a string they authored with content you usually might find in a phtml file. Mostly HTML, yes.